# Using Bugsnag with a sharing extension

Tags: ios, bugsnag

It seems evident, but I'm not seeing it in the docs:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ios/

For a sharing extension, do I need to add `Bugsnag.start()` into code that executes when the sharing extension launches? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bugsnag has specific instructions for [App Extensions](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ios/#app-extensions). You need to initialize Bugsnag within the extension view controller initializers.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    Bugsnag.start()
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind: An application extension creates a new target in your Xcode project. Bugsnag needs to be added to each target that you want to have access to the bugsnag-cocoa library.